# .net MD5 on stream

Tags: .net, io, md5

Lets say I'm doing something like:

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("xxx.xxx");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int count;
long pos = 0, length = fs.Length;

MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

while(pos < length && (count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
{
  doWork(buffer, count);
  md5.AddBlock(buffer, count); // <- Is this possible?
}

byte[] checksum = md5.GetChecksum(); // <- Possible?
```

I would like to be able to calculate the MD5 Checksum as I'm going through the stream... is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two methods you are looking for are [TransformBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx) and [TransformFinalBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformfinalblock.aspx). They will do exactly what you are looking for.

```
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("xxx.xxx");
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int count;
long pos = 0, length = fs.Length;

MD5 md5 = MD5.Create();

while(pos < length && (count = fs.Read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0)
{
  pos += count;
  doWork(buffer, count);
  int md5Offset = 0;

  //The while loop may be unnessasary, I don't know if it will ever process less than the length you pass in. The MSDN is unclear about that.
  while(md5Offset < count)
      md5Offset += md5.TransformBlock(buffer, md5Offset , count - md5Offset, buffer, md5Offset);
}

md5.TransformFinalBlock(buffer, 0, 0);
byte[] checksum = md5.Hash;
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `outputBuffer` be something other than `buffer`?

Comment: No, the API is weird, per the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.transformblock.aspx#remarksToggle) "Calling the TransformBlock method with different input and output arrays results in an IOException."

Comment: Huh... that's weird... but you're right. It doesn't change the `outputBuffer`. This seems to work great!